# Why open cavity decrease the number of oscillating modes?

Tags: laser-cavity

Number of modes inside a cavity for laser action is proportional to the volume now if I open the sides of the cavity then volume of the cavity becomes infinite so number of mode actually increase....so how. Open cavity helps to get small number of oscillating modes???

Comment: I don't think that "open cavity" in the context of, for example, HeNe lasers refers to opening the cavity volume literally, in order to have an infinite volume. Rather, what "open" means in the context of open cavity lasers is rather that the distance between the cavity mirrors so you can adjust the lasing inside of the cavity. Are these the lasers you are referring to?

Comment: Why would an opening develop any distinct oscillating mode?   It isn't any part of an oscillatory solution if it doesn't reflect.